# Where are the POSIX message functions (msgsnd, msgrcv, etc) man pages in Mac?

Tags: macos, messages

I wanted to view the manual pages for the POSIX standard message functions: msgsnd, msgrcv, etc. All of them are defined in *sys/msg.h* and code using them works. But the manual pages are nowhere to be found, neither in my computer (Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3), in my friends' (OS X Lion) or in the developer pages of Apple in Internet.

Where can I download that manual so I can access it right from terminal?

Comment: As a development issue (these are C calls) this is off topic here and should be on Stack Overflow

Comment: Man pages are part of the system (or should be) including sections 2 and 3. As long as no actual coding is involved (which would surprise me in this case), the question is suitable both for AD and for SO. For further discussions, please use [this thread](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/xcode-questions) on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download them from http://manpages.ubuntu.com.

For example, to download man page `msgsnd (3)`:

1. Search for `msgsnd` in the Google Custom Search field on the right hand side:

   [image]
2. Click on the newest man page in section 3:

   [image]
3. Download the linked .gz man page:

   [image]
4. Copy it to the man directory:

   - If you want to keep system and additional man pages apart, copy it to `/usr/local/share/man/man3/`:

     ```
     sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man3/
     sudo cp ~/Downloads/msgsnd.3posix.gz /usr/local/share/man/man3/
     ```

     and add:

     ```
     export MANPATH="/usr/local/share/man:$MANPATH"
     ```

     to `/etc/profile`, if you wish the new man page to be available system-wide, or `~/.bash_profile`, to be available to your user only (see `man man`, that is, `man`'s man page, for more information on `MANPATH`.)

     Open a new Terminal window or tab for changes to take effect.
   - Otherwise, copy the man page to `/usr/share/man/man3`:

     ```
     sudo cp /Users/jaume/Downloads/msgsnd.3posix.gz /usr/share/man/man3/
     ```
5. Enjoy:

   ```
   man 3 msgsnd

   MSGSND(P)                POSIX Programmer's Manual                MSGSND(P)

   NAME
          msgsnd - XSI message send operation
   (...)
   ```

Comment: So it's as easy as downloading them onto /usr/share/man/man3. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's that easy :-) If you want to keep system and additional man pages apart, copy them to `/usr/local/share/man/manX/` instead (edited the answer accordingly).